# Card Color Not Working Using Gesture Detector Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I am tired of something. I am following a course and I am trying to build a BMI calculator application but the color of the Male-female card does not update when I press it.

I have also used print('Male is selected') and it is showing me in the console that Gender.male or Gender.female is selected but the color is not changing. What am I doing wrong? I am new to flutter. Thanks.

Here is the code

reusable_card.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFF1D1E33),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

input_page.dart

```
Gender selectedGender;
enum Gender {
male,
female,
}

Expanded(
child: ReusableCard(
onPress: () {
setState(() {
selectedGender = Gender.female;
});
},
colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
? kActiveCardColour
: kInactiveCardColour,
cardChild: IconContent(
icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
label: 'FEMALE',
),
),
),
```

constants.dart

```
const kActiveCardColour = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const kInactiveCardColour = Color(0xFF111328);
```

Comment: Can you include full widget with the state? Currently, it looks like you are only setting the `selectedGender` to female, and nothing else changes it to male.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used the color you are passing :

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
           //pass the colour here
          color: Color(0xFF1D1E33),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your final widget should be like this :

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#reusable_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({required this.colour, this.childCard, this.onPress});
  final Color colour;
  final Widget? childCard;
  final VoidCallback? onPress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: childCard,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#input_page.dart

```
Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGender = GenderType.male;
                  });
                },
                childCard: IconContent(
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                  label: 'MALE',
                ),
                colour: selectedGender == GenderType.male
                    ? activeCardColour
                    : inactiveCardColour,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGender = GenderType.female;
                  });
                },
                childCard: IconContent(
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                  label: 'FEMALE',
                ),
                colour: selectedGender == GenderType.female
                    ? activeCardColour
                    : inactiveCardColour,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).